# Determine when laptop was last plugged in to power

Tags: power-management, battery, logging

I am looking for log entries of when my device is plugged and unplugged to/from mains power, or when the battery changes from discharging/charging state. Which log entries do I need to look for for this?

Comment: I don't have a laptop, but try `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i battery` and see.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have already tried `sudo grep -i battery /var/log/*` but nothing pertaining to charging is found.

Comment: Maybe here you'll find a clue for the ouput you want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113490/where-does-gnome-power-statistics-get-its-data-from):

UPower stores its historical information in four files in /var/lib/upower/
This is the data gnome-power-statistics uses to draw its charge/discharge profiles.
For example:

```
$ ls -t /var/lib/upower/* | head -4
/var/lib/upower/history-time-empty-AL15B33-48-3241.dat
/var/lib/upower/history-time-full-AL15B33-48-3241.dat
/var/lib/upower/history-charge-AL15B33-48-3241.dat
/var/lib/upower/history-rate-AL15B33-48-3241.dat
```

Looks like you could check charging/discharging state changes in the history-charge file:

```
$ cat history-charge-AL15B33-48-3241.dat
1475784954      58.000  discharging
1475785164      57.000  discharging
1475785344      56.000  discharging
1475785598      57.000  charging
1475786432      58.000  charging
```

Fist column is timestamp. You could use `date -s @timestamp` to get something more readable:

```
$ cat history-charge-AL15B35-48-3241.dat | while read f; do
  d=$(date +"%b %e %H:%M:%S" -s @`echo $f | cut -d\  -f1`);
  echo "$d  $f" ; done
Oct  6 22:15:54  1475784954      58.000  discharging
Oct  6 22:19:24  1475785164      57.000  discharging
Oct  6 22:22:24  1475785344      56.000  discharging
Oct  6 22:26:38  1475785598      57.000  charging
Oct  6 22:40:32  1475786432      58.000  charging
```

Comment: Awesome just what I was after. I knew the data had to exist somewhere! Thank you.

Comment: small correction: `date -d` not `-s`